# How do I disable automatic update checks while on battery power and on metered networks?

Tags: updates, power-management, 22.04, battery

Automatic updates are great and all, but they pop up nearly every time I log in (even from standby) - even when I'm on battery and have no intention of installing them until I get to a power outlet.

Even the check for the updates causes my CPU and power usage to spike, often causing the fan to spin up on my older Thinkpads.

Is there a way to restrict the automatic update check to only trigger when on AC power and on unmetered WiFi networks?

Running 22.04.1 LTS on multiple Thinkpads such as X220, W550s, X390.

Comment: 18.04 should have updates just a couple times each month -- it's old and very stable. Daily update reminders suggests that something else is wrong.

Comment: Don't forget there are different upgrade mechanisms; eg. the answer by @Ryan will work, but only for *deb* package upgrades (regardless of main Ubuntu or Ubuntu *flavor*), as *snap* packages work outside of this and have their own mechanism for upgrades.  That can be stopped too (*within limits; more accurately it's delayed intended, for metered networks - but those changes impact only snapd or snap packages*) with blogs telling you how to do this - but again only relating to *snap* package upgrades.  There is no *one single fix* that controls everything as there are multiple changes required

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about restricting update checks to specific situations, but you can stop Ubuntu from checking for updates automatically - at least on Ubuntu Studio, which uses KDE Plasma (so the options might be different for regular Ubuntu).

In my distro, I can go to System Settings - Driver Manager (which is under "Hardware"). From here I'm prompted to enter my password, after which the Software Sources window appears. In the Updates tab, I can change how often the system checks for updates or can disable the checks altogether.

Just remember to check for updates! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On regular Ubuntu with Gnome, settings like these exist but they seem to be ignored by the underlying update mechanism...

On my machines they're set to never automatically check for updates and I still get a popup every day.

To be clear, I mean the settings in the "Updates" tab of the "Software & Updates" settings dialog.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think I've also had, in the past, update settings set in one part of the system that weren't respected by the main updates program.